# Celery workers unable to connect to redis on docker instances

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, celery

I have a dockerized setup running a Django app within which I use Celery tasks. Celery uses Redis as the broker.

**Versioning:**

- Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
- docker-compose version 1.15.0, build e12f3b9
- Django==1.9.6
- django-celery-beat==1.0.1
- celery==4.1.0
- celery[redis]
- redis==2.10.5

**Problem:**

My celery workers appear to be unable to connect to the redis container located at localhost:6379. I am able to telnet into the redis server on the specified port. I am able to verify redis-server is running on the container.

When I manually connect to the Celery docker instance and attempt to create a worker using the command `celery -A backend worker -l info` I get the notice:

`[2017-11-13 18:07:50,937: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379/0: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address..
Trying again in 4.00 seconds...`

**Notes:**

I am able to telnet in to the redis container on port 6379. On the redis container, redis-server is running.

Is there anything else that I'm missing? I've gone pretty far down the rabbit hole, but feel like I'm missing something really simple.

**DOCKER CONFIG FILES:**

docker-compose.common.yml [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25956140/)
docker-compose.dev.yml [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25956144/)

Comment: Try replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Do you have a docker-compose file? Share it.

Comment: @Opal added config files to bottom of post.

Comment: @warvariuc same result when I change to 127.0.0.1. Also of note, using the docker IP address for the redis container also does not work.

Comment: It will definitely not be `localhost` since redis is not working doesn't work on the same host as celery. Can you ping redis via IP from celery?

Comment: You may also try `links` option in celery block that points to redis.

Comment: @Opal docker assigned IP for the redis instance is showing "IPAddress": "172.20.0.2", and I get no ping response from celery ("IPAddress": "172.19.0.4",)

Comment: @eht, then try `links` option, like here: https://github.com/codepotpl/codepot-backend/blob/master/docker-compose.yml. Then log to celery and run `export` or `printenv` to see the environment variables. Get the port and IP and try once again.

Comment: @Opal Yeah none of those changes seem to be doing the trick, unfortunately.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When you use docker-compose, you aren't going to be using `localhost` for inter-container communication, you would be using the compose-assigned hostname of the container. In this case, the hostname of your redis container is `redis`. The top level elements under `services:` are your default host names.

So for celery to connect to redis, you should try `redis://redis:6379/0`. Since the protocol and the service name are the same, I'll elaborate a little more: if you named your redis service "butter-pecan-redis" in your docker-compose, you would instead use `redis://butter-pecan-redis:6379/0`.

Also, docker-compose.dev.yml doesn't appear to have celery and redis on a common network, which might cause them not to be able to see each other. I believe they need to share at least one network in common to be able to resolve their respective host names.

[Networking in docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has an example in the first handful of paragraphs, with a docker-compose.yml to look at.

Comment: They did not share a common network, which helped resolve the issue.

Comment: if two of my containers are in the same network, this `redis://butter-pecan-redis:6379/0` way of connecting still work??(I don't want to use docker-compose)

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN No, it won't. Docker inherits the DNS of the host, so unless you have a DNS entry for `butter-pecan-redis` mapped to `localhost:<port>` somewhere outside of Docker, one container won't resolve another container by name. Docker-compose does something extra that allows this to work, I can't remember if it's something with a DNS per Docker network in compose, or if docker-compose adjusts hosts or resolv.conf. Either way, the simple by-name resolution is a docker-compose feature.

Comment: This was the missing piece of my puzzle to finally getting Docker, Django, Celery and Redis to work together from a docker-compose.yml file. Thanks for explaining this!

Answer (score 3):

You may need to add the [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links) and [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on) sections to your docker compose file, and then reference the containers by their hostname.

Updated docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
    db:
        image: postgres
    memcached:
        image: memcached
    redis:
        image: redis
        ports:
          - '6379:6379'
    backend-base:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: backend/Dockerfile-base
        image: "/backend:base"
    backend:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: backend/Dockerfile
        image: "/backend:${ENV:-local}"
        command: ./wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -- gunicorn backend.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -k gevent -w 3
        ports:
            - 8000
        links:
            - db
            - redis
            - memcached
        depends_on:
            - db
            - redis
            - memcached
    celery:
        image: "/backend:${ENV:-local}"
        command: ./wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -- celery worker -E -B --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=1
        environment:
            C_FORCE_ROOT: "yes"
        links:
            - db
            - redis
            - memcached
        depends_on:
            - db
            - redis
            - memcached
    frontend-base:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: frontend/Dockerfile-base
            args:
                NPM_REGISTRY: http://.view.build
                PACKAGE_INSTALLER: yarn
        image: "/frontend:base"
        links:
            - db
            - redis
            - memcached
        depends_on:
            - db
            - redis
            - memcached
    frontend:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: frontend/Dockerfile
        image: "/frontend:${ENV:-local}"
        command: 'bash -c ''gulp'''
        working_dir: /app/user
        environment:
            PORT: 3000
        links:
            - db
            - redis
            - memcached
        depends_on:
            - db
            - redis
            - memcached
```

Then configure the urls to redis, postgres, memcached, etc. with:

- `redis://redis:6379/0`
- `postgres://user:pass@db:5432/database`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your contribution. What do you mean exactly by "...configure the urls to redis, postgres, memcached..."?

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that all of the containers, including celery had a network argument specified. If this is the case the redis container must also have the same argument otherwise you will get this error. See below, the fix was adding 'networks':

```
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    networks:
      - server
```