# Mysqli Error 2002: no such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, docker, nginx

I am trying to run nginx, php, mysql together with docker.

When i run docker-compose, everything looks fine, but when i try to make a connection to mysql via php code in my index page i'm getting this error.

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /code/index.php on line 8
Connection failed: No such file or directory
```

- I have tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 and both with :3306 after it.

**When changing localhost --> 127.0.0.1, i'm getting another connection failed statement:**

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /code/index.php on line 8
Connection failed: Connection refused
```

**php code:**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "toor";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

echo phpinfo();

?>
```

Also when i look at `phpinfo();`, there is no value given to `mysqli.default_socket`.

when going into the mysql image after starting docker-compose, i'm able to go into mysql shell and execute commands just fine.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read my answer [from this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272072/celery-workers-unable-to-connect-to-redis-on-docker-instances/47273294#47273294). Localhost doesn't resolve like you think it should inside a container.

When you use a docker-compose.yml, you can reference the other services by their service name as specified in the docker-compose.yml. Your hostnames are not localhost, rather they are web, php, and mysql. So in your php code, you should use `$servername = "mysql";` instead of `$servername = "localhost";`

Comment: Wow i've been looking 2 days for this,  thanks!!

Comment: Ditto! Thanks for the solve.